# Sensors compatible with rpi 3

Tags: pi-3

Which sensors are recommended to use directly with Raspberry pi 3 for multigas readings and decibel meter (sound). The one I use are always reading zeros or rebooting (Using Raspberry pi libraries for Arduino controllers).

Comment: What does "Using Raspberry Pi libraries for Arduino controllers" mean? Which sensors are you using?

Comment: I would like to see the question expanded and the title made more explicit. I agree with you about the Pi libraries for Arduino controllers. ??? I think that it could be a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find that most, if not all, of the sensors you've been using are **analog** sensors. The Raspberry Pi has no analog input pins so you will get either incorrect readings, or no readings at all.

You will need an analog-to-digital converter for reading analog inputs, such as the **MCP3008**. You can take a look at what to do with the chip, and how to read it, at [RasPi.TV](http://raspi.tv/2016/using-mcp3008-to-measure-temperature-with-gpio-zero-and-raspio-pro-hat).

[image: RasPiO Pro HAT with MCP3008 chip]

If you want something easy to use, may I suggest the [Analog Zero add-on board](http://rasp.io/analogzero/) which has an MCP3008 on-board with pins broken out.

Alternatively, you may find that an I2C sensor is more to your liking such as the BMP280 (which replaced the BMP180) for temperature, humidity and pressure, for instance. There are a variety of I2C sensors.

For gas and decibels, you're almost certainly looking for analog sensors. Be very careful when using these sensors as they often require (and return) 5V. A 5V signal is bad for your Pi's GPIO pins and you will need a [level converter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757) that converts the 5V signal to 3v3. It may be that the 5V signal is what is causing your Pi to reboot. For gas, take a look at [the MQ series](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/Sensors/_resources/SNS-MQ-sensors.pdf) of sensors - it's best to get the ones on breakout boards, however - they tend to have the necessary resistor(s) already on-board.

Comment: Just love getting down-voted for something that took actual effort! :-(

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you didn't even ask what sensor was in use. Your answer is pretty much useless without this basic information from the OP.

Comment: "multigas readings" - well, given that only analog gas sensors in the MQ range are available and they're analog, my answer is pretty sensible. "decibel meter" - could be a few, but they're almost exclusively analog as far as I'm aware. At least I made a concerted effort to answer with the scant info available. In what way is the information "useless"?!